# Sample weights in LightGBM - where to specify?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, lightgbm, sample-weighting

I want to introduce samples weights to my lgbm classifier. From what I see the weights can be added both in the `lgb.Dataset` and in the `.fit` method. What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 2):

You can train a LightGBM model in two ways:

```
params = {}
my_data = lgb.Dataset(train_x, train_y, weights, ...)
my_model = lgb.train(params, my_data, ...)
```

or the Sklearn way:

```
my_model = lgb.LGBMClassifier(**params)
my_model.fit(train_x, train_y, weights...)
```

The `fit()` method doesn't take lgb.Dataset objects as input, the training data and their weights have to be passed separately.

You can find examples [here](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/examples/python-guide/simple_example.py) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/examples/python-guide/sklearn_example.py).

Comment: Só does It make any difference whether you specify the weights the first way or the second way?

Comment: In my experience, the two methods are equivalent, i.e. they give the same result.